# How to efficiently use S3 remote with DVC among multiple developers with different aws configs?

Tags: amazon-s3, dvc

The DVC remote configuration allows to define a profile for the AWS CLI to use. However, some developers might have their local AWS cli configuration use different profiles whose name they find helpful.

Is there a way to override the profile used by DVC on a dvc push / dvc pull without modifying the remote configuration of an s3 repo?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options to achieve this.

Use [`local`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#--local) remote config option to set remote storage config parameters that are specific to a user:

```bash
$ dvc remote modify --local myremote profile myprofile
```

It will create a file `.dvc/config.local` that will be Git-ignored, and options from this files will be merged with the main config when users run DVC commands.

Alternatively, users can use the `AWS_PROFILE` [environment variable](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables) to specify their local profile name. In this case remember to *not* include profile name into DVC remote config.

```bash
$ export AWS_PROFILE=myprofile 
$ dvc push
```

Comment: This is useful, how about running DVC in a CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: You can typically use env vars in CI/CD @Edmondo1984. You may also want to check CML (https://cml.dev/doc/cml-with-dvc) to make your life easier!

Comment: Thanks @JorgeOrpinelPérez, what I meant is that in the CI/CD typically you won't have an env var for the profile, but just for the secrets. Will these take priority over the config?

Comment: So, yes, in CI/CD you don't use profile at all. And in both options I've shared above `profile` won't be saved into Git at all also. It's be default in CI/CD.